# Not showing notifications when receiving a push event when the PWA is opened

Tags: push-notification, notifications, push, progressive-web-apps

This is a best practice question regarding the handling of push notifications in Pogressive Web Apps.

I'm currently developing a web app which contains a chat functionality. I added push notifications so the user gets a notification (via the NotificationsAPI) every time he receives a new chat message. This works fine. But receiving tons of push notifications even though the user has the chat window open is not a good user experience. Therefore i'd like to not show a notification at all if the user has the app open.

I know that not notifying the user about an incoming push is a critical topic and e.g. Chrome wants me to specify the `userVisibleOnly` flag. Is this a valid exception for not showing a notification or do you think i really need to show a notification every time a push is incoming? And if so, how can i deal with my problem? Anyone has any ideas how other apps are solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition: I may found the answer in one of Chromiums published documents:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/13VxFdLJbMwxHrvnpDm8RXnU41W2ZlcP0mdWWe9zXQT8/edit#

*"Each time a service worker finishes processing a push message but no notification from this origin is currently visible and there is no open and visible page on this origin*, we check whether any of the past 10 push messages received from this origin also didn’t leave a notification on display (and didn’t have a page from the origin open and visible). If that is the case then we display a notification on the sites behalf so they user can understand that it ran.

[...]

**: (as well as being same-origin, it must be from the same browser profile; it isn’t however required to have loaded successfully, i.e. error pages count, as long as omnibox is showing the correct domain)."*

As far as i understand it is allowed to not display notifications when the app is opened on the same device.